# setColumnRemarks is not supported on mysql using Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I am getting following error while running command line version of Liquibase V3.5.5

```
Unexpected error running Liquibase: Validation Failed:
1 changes have validation failures
  setColumnRemarks is not supported on mysql, PosMS1-V0.0.1- 
104.xml::1531369854279-1::otalio (generated)

liquibase.exception.ValidationFailedException: Validation Failed:
1 changes have validation failures
  setColumnRemarks is not supported on mysql, PosMS1-V0.0.1- 
104.xml::1531369854279-1::otalio (generated)
```

I was able to use Liquibase to add remarks to column while renaming and creating new columns, but it throws an error when I compute the diff of two databases which has only change in adding remark.

Comment: Please, post the changeSets you're executing

Comment: <changeSet author="otalio (generated)" id="1531369854279-1">
       <setColumnRemarks columnName="enter_tax" remarks="Enter Tax % out of range 0-100" tableName="OT_CON_TAX_RATE_B"/>
  </changeSet>